# Proper way to execute "g<Tab>" to switch to a previous tabpage from neovim

Tags: neovim

This works, but it's pretty ugly, just wondering if there's a better way:

```lua
vim.cmd[[exec "g\<Tab>"]]
```

None of these work:

```lua
vim.cmd.normal("g<Tab>")
vim.cmd.normal("g\<Tab>")
vim.cmd.normal("g\\<Tab>")
vim.cmd.exec("normal g<Tab>")
vim.cmd.exec("normal g\<Tab>")
vim.cmd.exec("normal g\\<Tab>")
```

Comment: I’m actually shocked the first one works; that should be doing the equivalent of `:global<Tab><enter>` which is kind of meaningless. In Vim I would expect `execute 'normal!' "g\<Tab>"` to work, but that depends on Vim’s string processing. What happens if you embed a literal tab in your commands (actually typing something like `normal! g<C-v><tab>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab is simply a tab, so `vim.cmd.normal"g\t"` works.

Also, in general, you may want to make use of `nvim_replace_termcodes()` function.